# composer --create command not working properly in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, migration

im using laravel 4.2, when i create a database migration file using composer command it generates migration file with

```
Schema::table('authors', function(Blueprint $table)
```

instead of

```
Schema::create('authors', function(Blueprint $table)
```

here is my migration command

```
php artisan migrate:make create_authors_table --table authors --create
```

i have tried composer update command still it doesnt work, can anyone please help me to get it sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the right format

```
php artisan migrate:make create_authors_table --create=authors
```

[Laravel Documentation for creating migration](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#creating-migrations)

Actually I would recommend using [way/generators](https://packagist.org/packages/way/generators)  for creating your models, controllers and migrations as it provides different types of generators which comes handy. Have a look at the [git hub page](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators)

Answer (score 0):

i have just used the following command and it works :)

```
php artisan migrate:make create_authors_table --create=authors
```